# no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError): how do i skip this error?

Tags: ruby

i'm writing a program related to a GSM possible discount and subscriber relationship. If the given tel number is amongst the array of subscribers then it also has a possible discount status... if true then it can have discount and it can't otherwise (false). If the telephone number happens not to be inside the subscribers array then the program should stop with just a last given message: "STATUS: INVALID"

```
subscribers = %w[5553457867 5417890987 5524567867 5356789865 5321234567 5546754321 5389876543]

starred_customer = [true, false, true, true, false, false, true]

def telephone_no_to_customer_index(subscribers, telephone_no) 
  subscribers.find_index do |number|
    telephone_no == number 
  end 
end

def starred_customer?(starred_customer, customer_index)  
  x = starred_customer[customer_index]
  if x == true
    puts "DISCOUNT: POSSIBLE"
  elsif x == false
    puts "DISCOUNT: IMPOSSIBLE"
  end
end

telephone_no = gets.chomp 
state = telephone_no_to_customer_index(subscribers, telephone_no)

state ? (puts "STATUS: VALID") : (puts "STATUS: INVALID")  #should i write here && (return)? 

customer_index = telephone_no_to_customer_index(subscribers, telephone_no)

discount_state = starred_customer?(starred_customer, customer_index)
puts discount_state
```

The program should skip everything else once the input telephone number is not inside of the subscribers array. Since the program doesn't stop, it passes "nil" as an argument to the second method and as the second method can't apply discount status to nil it gives an error: no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError):

What i want from the program is to just return "STATUS: INVALID" and stop if the telephone_no is not an element of the subscribers array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit the program on a certain condition, you can do that.

```
if not state
  puts "STATUS: INVALID"
  exit 
end

puts "STATUS: VALID"

customer_index = telephone_no_to_customer_index(subscribers, telephone_no)

discount_state = starred_customer?(starred_customer, customer_index)
puts discount_state
```

You could also use `unless`:

```
unless state
  puts "STATUS: INVALID"
  exit 
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I did as you said and it worked thanks a lot!

Comment: @therealramos Please consider upvoting when an answer was helpful and accepting when it solved your problem. This is a way to say thank you and to indicate to others that the problem you described can be solved by that answer.